# Two GPUs: Nvidia for display+OpenCL and R9 Fury X for OpenCL only. Possible?

Tags: nvidia, ati, opencl

For development reasons (mainly for testing OpenCL GPGPU kernels), I'd really benefit from having two GPUs on my system:

One of the latest Nvidia 9xx boards, for both display/OpenGL and for GPGPU OpenCL as well.

The other one, an AMD R9 Fury X, used for OpenCL GPGPU only (no display).

Is this possible? How should I install the hardware? And the drivers?

Will I get two platforms, AMD and NVIDIA, when querying OpenCL all available platforms?

Thanks!!

Comment: You want to mix nVidia *and* ATI drivers?  **Good luck!  You'll need it!** (I.o.w.: I wouldn't as no one does that and you'll be running into problems no one has ever had to solve, so you'll be all on your own trying to solve them...)  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby - I think it's possible, and I'm going to try something similar. I already have setup where AMD APU is accessible by OpenCL, and all the graphics goes through Nvidia card

Comment: @HEKTO: you should post an answer and ping me afterwards!  If it's any good, I'll upvote...